# how do I use LIKE in SQL with multiple search patterns?

Tags: sql, oracle, pattern-matching, sql-like, subquery

I have a DB with multiple tables. I want to retrieve two columns as illustrated in the example below:

`table name: stemp
column name: strsmall
Values:       x
               po
               r`

`table name: btemp
column name: str
 values:       xam
               power
               powerful
               xtra
               poke`

I want to have output like

`strsmall        str
x                 xam
p                 power
p                 powerful
x                 xtra
p                 poke`

There are hundreds of rows in each table in the actual database. the database I am using is oracle.

Comment: What you tried till now. can you post that query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select strsmall, str from stemp, btemp
where strsmall like '%'||str||'%'
or str like '%'||strsmall||'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LIKE statement as below:

```
select s.strsmall, b.str
from stemp s
inner join
btemp b on b.str like s.strsmall || '%'
```

Comment: The concatenation operator in Oracle is `||`, `+` is used for adding numbers together.

Comment: This only picks one the one that exact match with the string str and strsmall. This is not correct

Comment: I had it the wrong way round in my haste after copying from my query window and trying to change it to match your question